# Display new list item onclick with ReactJS

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, events, state

I have a problem with updating and displaying an array as list items on the click of a button. From below code, I get error message:

> list.map is not a function

```
import React from "react";


export default class InputPushToList extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      ActiveText: "",
      li: ["First Item"]
    };

    this.handleOnClick = this.handleOnClick.bind(this);
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(e) {
    this.setState({
      ActiveText: e.target.value
    });
  }

  handleOnClick(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    const newListItem = [this.state.ActiveText];

    this.setState({
      li: this.state.li.push(newListItem)
    });
  }

  render() {
    const list = this.state.li;
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <h2>{this.props.inputTitle}</h2>
        <input type="text" onChange={this.handleChange} />
        <h2>{this.state.ActiveText}</h2>
        <br />
        <button onClick={this.handleOnClick}>Add to list</button>

        <ul>
          {list.map(e => (
            <li>{e}</li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}
```

In my mind list.map is a function but apparently not, so why? And how would you go about displaying one more (that which is the active state of the input, this.state.ActiveText) list item when clicking the button? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### 1. Don't mutate `this.state`

In `handleOnClick()`, do not write `this.state.li.push(newListItem)`.

Instead, make a clone of `this.state.li`, add `newListItem` into that clone, and set the state of `li` to the new clone:

```
handleOnClick(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  this.setState({
    li: [
      ...this.state.li, // spread out the existing li
      this.state.ActiveText // append this newListItem at the end of this array
    ]
  });
}
```

#### 2. Consider destructuring

In your `render()`, you could *destructure* `this.state.li`:

```
render() {
  const { li } = this.state
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      ...other stuffs
      <ul>
        {li.map(e => (
          <li>{e}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First thing first, you don't use this.state inside this.setState, instead use a function to update state. Check this for reference: https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous

Your code should be as follows:

```
this.setState((state) => ({
  li: state.li.concat([newListItem])
}));
```

Second, why are you assigning an array to newlistitem by doing: `const newListItem = [this.state.ActiveText];` ?

It should be `const newListItem = this.state.ActiveText;`

Comment: Aight, so I changed the handleOnClick function to: `handleOnClick(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    const newListItem = this.state.ActiveText;

    this.setState(state => ({
      li: state.li.push(newListItem)
    }));
  }` But I still get the same error upon button click.

Comment: You are still not correcting the first mistake I mentioned. You dont use this.state in this.setState! Correct that first!  @Ronnlidd

Comment: Well, in that case, I don't understand this part of the link you included: `this.setState((state, props) => ({
  counter: state.counter + props.increment
}));`

Comment: Answer Updated FYR. @Ronnlidd

Comment: Is there a reason why push is worse than concat?

Comment: Because push() method adds one or more elements to the end of an array and returns the new length of the array. However what you want is not the length but the new array with element added. Hence use concat. I still reiterate, don't use this.state in setState.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is this line:

```
this.setState({
      li: this.state.li.push(newListItem)
    });
```

example:

```
var arr = [];
console.log(arr.push({}))// it will print 1.
```

in your case:

```
this.setState({
      li: this.state.li.push(newListItem)// here you assigned `li`1.
    });
```

Fix the above.